# toggle port rule on an ubuntu iptables firewall?

Tags: iptables

I have an ubuntu server which only allows traffic on a select group of ports via iptables. One of the ports that is set to `REJECT` by default is `53`.

I need to periodically open port 53 to run an instance of `acme-dns` to authenticate `DNS-01` challenges from *LetsEncrypt*, then close it when finished.

Is there an easy way this can be automated?  I know how to easily automate *adding* a rule via `iptables -I` to insert an `ACCEPT` for `udp` traffic `53` at the top of the list, but the only way I know how to disable a particular rule is to list all active rules with line numbers and disable the particular rule by line number.  That requires manual interaction on my part.

I need remove that rule, and not undo it by inserting a `REJECT` before it, because this will be run by a cron job and I don't want pollute the rules with a bunch of ACCEPT/REJECT toggles that undo one another.

The only approach I can think of is to write a script that prints the rules by line number, analyzes them, then drops the matching rule.  Is there a way to do this simply with an iptables command that I don't know of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules can be managed more easily by using an user-defined chain.

Create a chain:

```
iptables -N acme-dns
```

Call this chain with this command run at the right place in the iptables script, before the REJECT rule for port 53:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j acme-dns
```

Normally this chain is empty and there's no effect. When access to acme-dns is needed, this command can be run (it could be more precise, but that's not the point here):

```
iptables -A acme-dns -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

When access is not needed anymore, the chain's content can be flushed. Even if for some reason the previous command was added multiple times, this will anyway flush all entries:

```
iptables -F acme-dns
```

For this simple case, that's really all that is needed. For complex cases involving a lot of dynamic changes to values (ports, ips...) but not rules, the set match module and [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) can help for performance and management.

Comment: brilliant! i did not think of a custom chain.  thank you!